# Can we execute map() on List, which is generated from collect() in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am curious to understand where will the Transformations execute(Inside executor or Driver) when the are specified after an action. Suppose below is the rough flow of Transformations and actions.

```
val R1 = Rdd.map(...);  
val R2 = R1.filter(...);
val R3 = R2.flatMap(...);
```

Untill the above, the instructions execute on Executor in a distributed manner.

`val lst = R3.collect();` --> Collect will also be executed in Distributed Manner I suppose. Please correct if i am wrong. It sends back the output to Driver.

Now CAN we execute map() like below?

```
lst.map(...)
```

If we can, then where will this code execute? on Driver or Executor?

Comment: Try to print out the type of `lst`. Is it a Spark dataframe or an object from the Scala Standard library?

Answer (score 0):

Spark follows lazy evaluation which means it will start the job only when there is an action applied.

In your example `R3.collect()` is the action which triggers to run your entire lineage. Yes collect() will run in distributed way and will return all the transformed data to Driver node. Once it is done your `lst` variable is going to be an in memory collection (array).

Since `lst` is an array `lst.map(...)` is possible and it is going to run on Driver.

---

> Important point to note, if you working with really large data set
>   and doing collect is a bad practice as it will bring entire data into
>   Driver which often given OOM exception.

---

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am unable to find map() in List class. Can you please let me know in which class this method resides? The collect() is returning Java List and it is not a RDD. So how can map() be applied on a Java Object?

Comment: it will give you array not java List eg. `scala> sc.parallelize("hello world").collect.map(a => a)
res20: Array[Char] = Array(h, e, l, l, o,  , w, o, r, l, d)`

Comment: if you are still getting Java list use `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and  do `list.toList`

Comment: I am using JavaSpark. 
In Java, sc.parallelize("hello world") throws error since the argument it expects is List and we are passing string(Although, technically it is a List of Characters). In Scala it works fine. 
In JavaSpark, the collect() returns List and the List Class doesn't have a map(). 
In scala, the List class contains map(). 
May be that is the reason i am unable to use map() on List in Java.

Comment: Alright, got it! we have map methods in scala not in java for the in memory collection. You can for loops in java to loop thru lst